# sql server, Partitioned table taking long on a query

Tags: sql-server, performance, partitioning

I have a table with the below structure:

```
acct_no,
purchase_date,
auth_id,
seq_no,
.
.
.
other columns
```

The table is partitioned on purchase_date. So, there is a partition for every month.

There are around 280 million records in the table.

The primary key of the table is `(acct_no, purchase_date, auth_id, seq_no)`.

When do the below query it works fine:

```
select top 1 * from table where acct_no = some_value and purchase_date > some_value order by acct_no, purchase_date, auth_id, seq_no
```

But, when I do the below query it takes a lot of time:

```
select top 1 * from table where acct_no > some_value order by acct_no, purchase_date, auth_id, seq_no
```

Without partitioning, the queries work fine. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Well as I guess, if you have partition by `purchase_date` then in first select it will use it and will search faster, as in second select looks for it in all table (so it takes more time). Would be nice to try, if this select will search long too, when you put `some_value=1970` (minimum possible value) in  `purchase_date > some_value`

Comment: Had forgot the order by clause which I have added now.

Comment: Shouldn't the query use the PK index and get the next record quickly? I see that when I set the minimum value for the date, then also it is performing slow. So, if we dont eliminate enough partitions, then the queries are going to be slow. what is the solution around this?

Comment: Well, the table is partitioned by `purchase_date` - of course queries that don't align with that partitioning are going to be slower than without it. This would be different if you switched the order of `acct_no` and `purchase_date` in the composite index - in that case, the non-partitioned table would probably be slower than the partitioned one even when searching by `acct_no`. Composite indices are tricky, even more so when partitioning is involved.